# inserting into SQLite database

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am very much new to Sqlite operation,
Until now I was operating only to UI + some Web service

What I am facing issue is that,

I am creating a table from Terminal and inserting values in it from Xcode by matching the table name.
The table consist for 4 fields, out of which 2 belongs to table and 2 are foreign keys.

When even I insert the Query my app FREEZES at that point.

It doesn't move further, not allowing any operations.

Here is my query

```
-(bool)insertMatchSampleQuest:(QuestionDTO*)questionDTO
{
   NSMutableArray* matchQesA=[questionDTO matchQuesA];

    NSLog(@"MTQ QuestionsArray :- %@",[matchQesA description]);
    NSLog(@"MTQ QuestionsArray count :- %d",[matchQesA count]);

    FMDatabase* db=[SqlLiteDAOFactory createConnection];

    for(int i=0;i<[matchQesA count];i++)
    {
        MTQuestionDTO *mTQuestionDTO =[matchQesA objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"value of testsample id is :- %@",questionDTO.testsampledid);
        NSLog(@"value of sampletest id is :- %@",questionDTO.sampletestid);
        NSLog(@"value of MTQ Question id :- %@",mTQuestionDTO.mtq_question_id);
        NSLog(@"value of MTQ Question Text :- %@",mTQuestionDTO.mtq_question_text);

        [db executeUpdate:@"insert into matchquestion (testsampledID,sampletestid,mtq_question_id,mtq_question_text) values(?,?,?,?)",questionDTO.testsampledid,questionDTO.sampletestid,mTQuestionDTO.mtq_question_id,mTQuestionDTO.mtq_question_text];

        if ([db hadError])
        {
            NSLog(@"database error");
            NSLog(@"Err in inserting %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
            [db close];

        }

    }
    [db close];
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I NSlog the values, it gives me proper values.
Also when I fire the same query from Terminal value get inserted into database.

I am firing this Query to my Array count.
I am having total Array, and want to insert the elements into table till array count.

Why my app is FREEZING, if its error then It must go in Error block, its not going there,
So I am facing difficulties to track it.

What a mistake I made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's freezing, that would suggest that you must have some other query open at the same time, which is blocking this one. It is impossible for us to confirm this on the basis of the code supplied. You should have only one `FMDatabase` object at one time (and if you're using it from multiple threads, use `FMDatabaseQueue` instead).

Comment: Hi @ROb, please find my above code edited, hope that Will help to understand what I am doing creating object of FMDATABASE at start and dealing at end

Comment: @stallone: See my below answer

Comment: @stallone Thanks, but my concern was whether you might have some completely separate `FMDatabase` instance elsewhere that might be locking the database in question.

Comment: @Rob, If I Remove the testsampledID field from Query then data get inserted properly. That coloumn is foreign key for the table whose value I am fetching from select Query and strain into NSString and passing that NSString. So After removing the field it works fine. I checked for Select query close DB, it is also closed well, still I am facing this freezing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `[db close];` from your below code : or break the loop.

```
   if ([db hadError])
    {
        NSLog(@"database error");
        NSLog(@"Err in inserting %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        [db close];  // Remove this line, or break the loop.
        break;

    }
```

Its FREEZING because when error execute, it will close DB but not exited from loop,that's why in next iteration its try to perform DB operation but you close the DATA base in previous iteration already.

Comment: I tried that thing, didn't help.
Actually my control goes in that if loop if there is error in connection or Query creation. so If error found then it simple closes DB and returns the control.
Thanks for this, but didn't helped.

Comment: Perhaps, but, nonetheless, this error clause should _not_ close the database (as that happens when you leave the loop) and definitely _should_ `break`. Or go ahead and `close` the database, but then `return` to exit not only the loop but the method as well. But don't `close` the database but remain in this loop.

Comment: @ Rob : Thanks for more clarification. May be now its works for @stallone.

Comment: @Rob & Divya:- Thanks for your help. I was firing select query to get id and result set was not closed, DB was closed. b'se of which it was freezing